# Windows environment variable not being read on Heroku

Tags: python, django, windows, heroku

I am creating a Django Application and deploying it using the heroku command line interface with git 
I set environment variables and called them in my settings.py file but i kept getting an error that the secret key was empty and the app could not be built

This is my settings.py file

```
    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    #SECRET_KEY = 't9iu8f#m48b)#vrjcm1(ek7#hlv9qc1&pu+h)ofz^^d_r10t(d'


    SECRET_KEY= os.environ['secretKey']
    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ashesidocconnect.herokuapp.com']


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'Connect.apps.ConnectConfig',
        'users.apps.UsersConfig',
        'crispy_forms',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django_filters',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'DocConnect.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DocConnect.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/


    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'



    CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'Connect-docInfo' #Change this to the path for the user authenticated log in 

    LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

This is my manage.py file

```
import os
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DocConnect.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my wsgi.py file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DocConnect.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is the full stacktrace gotten when pushing the code into the heroku server

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/tmp/build_75cfa40c4bef31821ef48fa975e4938c/DocConnect/settings.py", line 26, in <module>
remote:            SECRET_KEY= os.environ['secretKey']
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
remote:            raise KeyError(key) from None
remote:        KeyError: 'secretKey'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

Comment: This looks pretty straightforward: that environment variable isn't present. How did you try to set it?

Comment: I set it in the windows advanced system settings environment variables

Answer (score 0):

> I set environment variables in my Windows advanced system settings

[Environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) are *environment*-specific. Setting them in Windows won't affect Heroku.

Heroku's [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) are really environment variables for your app. Set them using the `heroku config:set` command, e.g.

```
heroku config:set secretKey=some-secret-value
```

Alternatively, you can set them in Heroku's web-based portal.

Incidentally, I noticed that you're using SQLite. That won't work on Heroku. Consider migrating to a client-server database like PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you for the organizing. Initially i tried the command you suggested and it still gave me a keyError but when i hardcoded the raw secret key into the settings.py file everything deployed perfectly. Oh yeah i am also using a PostgreSQL database for the actual webApp.

Comment: "when i hardcoded the raw secret key into the settings.py file everything deployed perfectly"—that doesn't really solve the problem, does it? Not hardcoding your secret key is a best practice. If I were you, I'd dig into _why_ it's not working. Did you use the same case everywhere?

Comment: Yeah thats why i posted the problem here cause im looking everywhere and cant seem to find out how to let heroku access it (for windows specifically). Did i use the same case everywhere? Please what does this mean

Comment: See, you're talking about Windows again. Windows has nothing whatsoever to do with this. It's _entirely_ on the Heroku side. "Same case" means capitalization. You're trying to use `secretKey` in your code, which is a bit strange. A more common variable name would be `SECRET_KEY`. In any case, are you using `secretKey` everywhere, and not `secretkey` or `SecretKey` or `SECRETKEY`?